# The HTML Form of my website don't send the infos anywhere

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have set up a little website,

In which I have a little form,

But when the user press the submit button nothing happens,

Indeed there is no indication on where to send the information,

I don't know how to do it,

I would like the receive an email directly in my inbox when someone press submit.

```
<div class = "col-sm-6">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" 
type="text" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" 
type="email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" 
type="tel">
    </div>
  </div>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" 
placeholder="Message" rows="5"></textarea><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>
      </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to add a form element around your input fields, and then target that to a script that processes the information and emails it to you using some back-end technology (i.e. ASP.Net, PHP etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `<form>` tags and to specify where to send the data on the server.

```html
<!-- doesnt have to be PHP can be any server side technology. !-->
 <form action="/yourEmailer.php/"> 
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" type="tel">
      </div>
    </div>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Message" rows="5"></textarea><br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a form. You only have form controls (i.e. inputs and the like).

You need to add [a `<form>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) so the submit button has something to submit.

To receive an email, you need to set the `action` attribute of the form element to a server side script that will process the data and send you the email. The specifics of this will depend on which programming language you choose along with your server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Follow this example. 
Save your file as .php extension 
Then add this line on top of your form code 
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["name"])){
$name = $_POST["name"];
mail("yourmail@gmail.com","My subject",$name); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this without specific action declared in `<form action="">` attribute.

The only thing you can do similar thing in pure HTML is to trigger new e-mail in you desktop client by adding 
`<a href="mailto:YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS">Send me an email</a>`

where you can specify some parameters like [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_mailto)

There's no way to this without back-end script written (the simplest way if you have basic hosting) in PHP